# Can "sum" and "nemo" work together to create a phrase meaning "I am no one?"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, grammar-choice, poetry

I have been trying to understand the relationship between "sum" and "nemo", to create a phrase meaning something like "I am no one". In all the contexts I personally could find them near each other in Latin, they weren't used as a phrase at all (see answers for an example I didn't find). It tends to be something more like (which it has been pointed out is nonsensical):

> Dico igitur ab eruditus vir, nisi sapiens, liber **sum nemo**.
>
> It has been said then, that **no one** is free except the wise man.

From: Andrews, E. A. (1868). *Latin Exercise Adapted to Andrews and Stoddards Latin Grammar.* United States: Crocker and Brewster.

I'm not sure where the **sum** went, unless it's the **is**? Which makes me wonder if this is something that would make sense at all? It's been quite a few years since my last Latin lesson in grammar, but something seems off.

However, in trying to figure this out I ran across this question,
[How to say 'I am myself'?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/how-to-say-i-am-myself), where emphatic translation would be **ego egomet sum**, with the explanation that **egomet**/**myself** is a predicate nominative. Which makes me think that something like **ego nemo sum** would make sense, as **nemo** would be a noun modifying **ego**.

I also read [How would you say “we are no one”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/how-would-you-say-we-are-no-one), which brings up **nihil** and says something about "oblique forms", which confused me (because it's incorrect as pointed out in the comments on this question), but seemed to indicate that **nihil** might be preferable. Which would give us **Ego nihil sum**, a phrase apparently used by Cicero, but I'm unsure how (I can't find the intended translation of that). Again, it feels a bit strange. **Ego nil sum** likewise, but it looks to have been used in a poetic/religious sense in places I can't find translations of.

This is my first question, so I apologize if it's less than great, I was a bit overwhelmed trying to write it (It may have taken me about 5 hours originally).

Further context is that this is part of something larger I'm working on, which is trying to figure out the Latin for **I am nothing if I am myself**. My current understanding is that it'd be **Ego nihil sum si ego egomet sum**, but something tells me that the first part of that (if it indeed works) would change something about the latter part (irrelevance of word order notwithstanding). I suppose those might be topics for future questions. There is also the question of declaring how Romans would view a self-declaration that you are no one, for another day.

Comment: Please note that the Latin sentence from E. A. Andrews is grammatical gibberish. It is [apparently](https://books.google.de/books?id=CGwSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA247) a form of prose composition exercise where the student is supposed to put all the words in their proper form. I think the proper form is: *Dictum igitur est ab eruditissimis viris neminem esse librum nisi sapientem.* (Unless I fail at this prose composition exercise, which would not be the first time.)

Comment: Regarding the remark about oblique forms: “Oblique forms” is a fancy term for “other cases than the nominative,” and the remark is incorrect: the dative and accusative forms *nemini* and *neminem* were used in classical Latin.

Comment: By the way, this is definitely a *great* first post! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

Yes!

*Nemo est qui...* is a common enough formula in Latin, "there is no one who...". Since *nemo* can be used with *est* there is no reason it cannot be used with *sum*.

Indeed the phrase *nemo sum homo* is attested. See [here](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=nemo%20sum).

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context for the latter example? Perhaps how it's used in that sentence?

Comment: It's a fragmentary text, so there is not a lot of context: *Quis tu homo es? nemo sum homo.* (What man are you? I am no man.)

Comment: Excellent. Is the use of both "nemo" and "homo" for emphasis on "man", then?

Comment: @Lulah Indeed. *Nemo homo* is actually pleonastic, since *nemo* is just a contraction for *ne homo* (no man). So *nemo homo* is just an emphatic way to say *nemo*.

Comment: Makes good sense. So would my original thought of "Nemo sum si egomet sum" would work as an unemphatic "I am no one if I am myself"?  
Did I go too far with "Ego Nihil..."? Or would that also work as an emphatic version?

Comment: (Should I just break that off into a specific translation question?)

Comment: @Lulah I think that *nemo sum si egomet sum* makes about as much sense as such an oracular saying can.